# How can I merge wav files from gcp storage bucket (in memory) and upload to another bucket, using wave libraray in python

Tags: google-cloud-storage, wave

I am able to merge the files downloaded from a google cloud storage bucket using wave library but unable to upload it post merging.

Here is the code (currently it saves the merged file locally and uploads from there):

```
def join_wav_files():
    data = list()
    in_storage_client = storage_util()
    app_config = load_cfg('config/app.yml')
    all_files_dict = dict()
    source_bucket = in_storage_client.get_bucket(app_config["wav_files_storage_bucket"])
    blobs = source_bucket.list_blobs(prefix=app_config["hi_folder"])
    dest_bucket = in_storage_client.get_bucket(app_config["wav_files_merged_bucket"])
    dest_blob = dest_bucket.blob("merged.wav")
    for file in blobs:
        if not file.name.endswith('/'):
            with file.open("rb") as f:
                w = wave.open(f, 'rb')
                data.append([w.getparams(), w.readframes(w.getnframes())])
                w.close()

    output = wave.open(os.path.join(os.getcwd(), "merged.wav"), 'wb')
    output.setparams(data[0][0])
    for i in range(len(data)):
        output.writeframes(data[i][1])
    output.close()

    dest_blob.upload_from_filename('merged.wav')
```